# Postgres SQL - strange performance issue in select

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, postgresql-performance

I have query (simplified version):

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT id, foo(id) AS foo FROM test)
SELECT id FROM temp WHERE foo = 4;
```

`foo(id)` is function that returns 0, 2 or 4 (only these values)

Above query with `... WHERE foo = 4` takes minutes, but surprisingly when I change to `... WHERE foo != 0 AND foo != 2` query performance is milliseconds.

Same if I do `... WHERE foo > 2` - also super fast.

I checked execution plan but I don't see any differences.

Very surprised by that ... can someone explain me why?

Comment: It is a function.The planner has no  idea of what to expect.

Comment: ok, agree - but how does this impact foo = 4 vs foo > 2, in both cases it has no idea.

Comment: This question would be a lot more useful with the actual function and table definitions, your version of Postgres, and the actual query plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the function `foo()` cannot be inlined, Postgres has no idea what it might return, so it has to assume that any number is equally common.

The predicate `foo = 4` tells Postgres to expect that **next to no row** will qualify.

The predicate `foo != 0 AND foo != 2`, OTOH, tells Postgres to expect that **almost all rows** qualify. With `foo > 2` it's still about half of all rows.

That typically leads to different query plans, and the first one seems to perform poorly, while the other ones seem to perform nicely.

Details are hidden by missing information. But that's the point here.

If the function is `IMMUTABLE`, you might create an expression index on `foo(foo(id))`. That index is probably useless by itself, assuming that the 3 possible values are evenly distributed. (*Maybe* an index-only scan for a multicolumn index `foo(foo(id), id)` would help, if the function is expensive and declared as such.) But it makes Postgres gather additional statistics that would tell the query planner what to expect from the function. Related:

- [Index that is not used, yet influences query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/72649/3684)

Comment: Thanks - makes sense. I can't post exact function it's way too complex. It's STABLE and receives more parameters so I can't really use expression index. I wonder if I would return ENUM with 3 values instead INTEGER - would it help.